# Regex behaviour is different on terminal from online validators

Tags: regex, shell, awk

I made a regex to extract values from a templated string. The regex is working smooth on websites like regexr.com but it's failing when I try to run in shell.

As example, let's use those lines:

> [2022-11-11T12:07:00.789Z] "GET /check?subject=johnbegucci HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" 0 17 3 2 "-" "-" "4e4c4fb1-a4d8-4075-8e42-b5fb9216f863" "laundry.transaction.svc.cluster.local:4466" "172.16.107.246:4466" outbound|4466||laundry.transaction.svc.cluster.local 172.16.67.246:51630 10.100.111.246:4466 172.16.67.246:48610 - default
>
> [2022-11-11T13:31:41.189Z] "GET /v1/campaign/198237-jsd-1231 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" 0 674 63 63 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/11.0.7)" "9b3afd5b-c092-4e84-9f29-6380b7f2cafc" "mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor" "172.16.108.138:80" outbound|80||mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor.svc.cluster.local 172.16.65.24:57134 10.100.19.249:80 172.16.65.24:38816 - default

Both lines follows the pattern:

> [%START_TIME%] "%REQ(:METHOD)% %REQ(X-ENVOY-ORIGINAL-PATH?:PATH)% %PROTOCOL%" %RESPONSE_CODE% %RESPONSE_FLAGS% %BYTES_RECEIVED% %BYTES_SENT% %DURATION% %RESP(X-ENVOY-UPSTREAM-SERVICE-TIME)% "%REQ(X-FORWARDED-FOR)%" "%REQ(USER-AGENT)%" "%REQ(X-REQUEST-ID)%" "%REQ(:AUTHORITY)%" "%UPSTREAM_HOST%" %UPSTREAM_CLUSTER% %UPSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS% %DOWNSTREAM_LOCAL_ADDRESS% %DOWNSTREAM_REMOTE_ADDRESS% %REQUESTED_SERVER_NAME%\n

Based on that, I created this regex to extract values from `UPSTREAM_HOST`. Values like `outbound|4466||laundry.transaction.svc.cluster.local`:

```
(\[.*\])\s(\".*\")\s([0-9]*)\s(.*)\s(\".*\")\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)+
```

I have tested this regex on website  regexr.com and it displays right values as group 14 for both lines:

```
outbound|4466||laundry.transaction.svc.cluster.local
outbound|80||mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor.svc.cluster.local
```

After that, I tried to execute an `awk -v FPAT` but the groups looks wrong. To get values from `UPSTREAM_HOST`, I need to change print value and it's not viable because I'm creating an automation to process log:

```
echo '[2022-11-11T12:07:00.789Z] "GET /check?subject=johnbegucci HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" 0 17 3 2 "-" "-" "4e4c4fb1-a4d8-4075-8e42-b5fb9216f863" "laundry.transaction.svc.cluster.local:4466" "172.16.107.246:4466" outbound|4466||laundry.transaction.svc.cluster.local 172.16.67.246:51630 10.100.111.246:4466 172.16.67.246:48610 - default' | awk -v FPAT='(\[.*\])\s(\".*\")\s([0-9]*)\s(.*)\s(\".*\")\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)+' -v OFS='|' '{print $15}'

# above example im using '{print $15}'

echo '[2022-11-11T13:31:41.189Z] "GET /v1/campaign/198237-jsd-1231 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" 0 674 63 63 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/11.0.7)" "9b3afd5b-c092-4e84-9f29-6380b7f2cafc" "mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor" "172.16.108.138:80" outbound|80||mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor.svc.cluster.local 172.16.65.24:57134 10.100.19.249:80 172.16.65.24:38816 - default' | | awk -v FPAT='(\[.*\])\s(\".*\")\s([0-9]*)\s(.*)\s(\".*\")\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)+' -v OFS='|' '{print $18}'
 
# above example im using '{print $18}'
```

Is there any way to make it work for both logs with same `print` position?

Comment: If you want to use a PCRE regex, your options are 1) Perl; 2) Ruby; 3) GNU Grep. Bash and awk have simpler flavors of regex and yours will not work.

Comment: Can I extracting using grep? Didnt know about that

Comment: GNU grep only -- not POSIX grep

Comment: What is the difference of GNU grep and posix one? I think that Im using GNU

Comment: Verifying a regexp on some web site proves that that regexp works on that web site, don't assume it'll work in any given command-line tool as there's too many possible regexp variants, extensions, delimiters, backreference options, etc. Also, don't get hung up on trying to do so much with just regexps - remember [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need such complex regex to parse log entries shown in question.

Consider this `awk` solution with a simpler regex:

```bash
awk -v FPAT='\\[[^]]*]|"[^"]*"|\\S+' '
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) print NR ":" i "::"$i
}' file.log

1:1::[2022-11-11T12:07:00.789Z]
1:2::"GET /check?subject=johnbegucci HTTP/1.1"
1:3::200
1:4::-
1:5::"-"
1:6::0
1:7::17
1:8::3
1:9::2
1:10::"-"
1:11::"-"
1:12::"4e4c4fb1-a4d8-4075-8e42-b5fb9216f863"
1:13::"laundry.transaction.svc.cluster.local:4466"
1:14::"172.16.107.246:4466"
1:15::outbound|4466||laundry.transaction.svc.cluster.local
1:16::172.16.67.246:51630
1:17::10.100.111.246:4466
1:18::172.16.67.246:48610
1:19::-
1:20::default
2:1::[2022-11-11T13:31:41.189Z]
2:2::"GET /v1/campaign/198237-jsd-1231 HTTP/1.1"
2:3::200
2:4::-
2:5::"-"
2:6::0
2:7::674
2:8::63
2:9::63
2:10::"-"
2:11::"Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/11.0.7)"
2:12::"9b3afd5b-c092-4e84-9f29-6380b7f2cafc"
2:13::"mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor"
2:14::"172.16.108.138:80"
2:15::outbound|80||mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor.svc.cluster.local
2:16::172.16.65.24:57134
2:17::10.100.19.249:80
2:18::172.16.65.24:38816
2:19::-
2:20::default
```

I have printed like this to show you each and every field in each record.

Comment: GNU awk that...

Comment: Hey @anubhava! This command fails with echo:
`echo '[2022-11-11T13:31:41.189Z] "GET /v1/campaign/198237-jsd-1231 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" 0 674 63 63 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/11.0.7)" "9b3afd5b-c092-4e84-9f29-6380b7f2cafc" "mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor" "172.16.108.138:80" outbound|80||mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor.svc.cluster.local 172.16.65.24:57134 10.100.19.249:80 172.16.65.24:38816 - default' | awk -v FPAT='\\[[^]]*]|"[^"]*"|\\S+' '{print $15}'` ... the output is `9b3afd5b-c092-4e84-9f29-6380b7f2cafc` instead of `outbound...`.

Comment: Should I send all data to a file before apply awk?

Comment: In my testing I got `$15` value as: `outbound|80||mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor.svc.cluster.local`.

Comment: [Here is a working demo](https://ideone.com/JIqNGu). You can text for `3:15::`

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples in any `awk` please try following `awk` code. Using regex `\[[^]]*\]|"[^"]*"|[^[:space:]]+` in a while loop using `match` function to match this regex(to get all matches in each line), if match found then print matched values as per requirement.

```bash
awk '
{
  count=0
  while(match($0,/\[[^]]*\]|"[^"]*"|[^[:space:]]+/)){
    print NR ":" ++count "::" substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
'   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are happy with that regex, you can use Perl to execute it:

```
s1='[2022-11-11T12:07:00.789Z] "GET /check?subject=johnbegucci HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" 0 17 3 2 "-" "-" "4e4c4fb1-a4d8-4075-8e42-b5fb9216f863" "laundry.transaction.svc.cluster.local:4466" "172.16.107.246:4466" outbound|4466||laundry.transaction.svc.cluster.local 172.16.67.246:51630 10.100.111.246:4466 172.16.67.246:48610 - default'

s2='[2022-11-11T13:31:41.189Z] "GET /v1/campaign/198237-jsd-1231 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" 0 674 63 63 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.10 (Java/11.0.7)" "9b3afd5b-c092-4e84-9f29-6380b7f2cafc" "mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor" "172.16.108.138:80" outbound|80||mkt-extractor.mkt-extractor.svc.cluster.local 172.16.65.24:57134 10.100.19.249:80 172.16.65.24:38816 - default'


echo "$s1" | perl -lnE 'say $14 if /(\[.*\])\s(\".*\")\s([0-9]*)\s(.*)\s(\".*\")\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)+/'
"172.16.107.246:4466"

echo "$s2" | perl -lnE 'say $14 if /(\[.*\])\s(\".*\")\s([0-9]*)\s(.*)\s(\".*\")\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s([0-9]*)\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(\".*\")\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)\s(.*)+/'
"172.16.108.138:80"
```

Answer (score 0):

depending on how certain you are regarding whether there are any more double-quotes (`"`) after the desired `IP address`, or any pipes (`|`) before it, these should mostly work :

> ```
> mawk NF=NF FS='^.*" "|" [^|]+[|].+$' OFS=
> ```

```
172.16.107.246:4466
172.16.108.138:80
```

> ```
> gawk NF=NF FS='^.*" "|"[^"]+$' OFS=
> ```

```
172.16.107.246:4466
172.16.108.138:80
```